# Any downsides to using a CMS for a high-risk website?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I'm helping a client with their website (it's manually written using a Dreamweaver template and a *ton* of quadruple-nested table elements for design. *Ouch*), and I want to offer them a break from using Dreamweaver to write things.

I was thinking of using Wordpress or a similar CMS to do the job, as Wordpress is clean, fast, and *really* easy to design for. I've done it a few times, and it's almost as easy as just coding pure HTML.

My main concern is that the site has been hacked a few times before, even though it was *pure* HTML with no server-side code whatsoever. I can setup a manual Linux server for them, because the hosting company they use is one that I've never heard of.

The site owners are completely technologically impaired, so I don't want to scare them off by showing them a dynamic CMS with tons of features, as they think pure HTML is so much safer, they have to go out of their way to work with it.

I know this is a ton of writing, but what would be the *most appropriate CMS* for such a setup (hard-coding or dynamically generating content) for such a setup? I don't want to keep having the person manually write non-standards compliant quadruple-nested table layouts anymore, but I don't want to be responsible for having their site hacked...

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, *I* wanted to redesign wikileaks.org!  :)

Comment: I wouldn't call WordPress *clean...*  Easy to design for?  Sure.

Comment: Why do you want to offer them a break from using DW? What are the specific reasons for the switch? Because while DW may not create the best code on earth, it's arguably the safest way to build the HTML locally, and upload the finished files. Any CMS and dynamic language you expose on the site will bring some risk of being exploited

Comment: "CMS of choice" is subjective.  You may want to reword your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that allows for local editing, and the uploading of only static HTML files, would be the safest way to go. If it's a high-risk site, I would consider staying on that track.

If a site containing only static HTML was hacked, then most likely through some problem on web server or even operating system level - I am not aware of any exploits concerning static HTML resources. Problems usually come up when dynamic languages are involved.

Whatever you do, don't use Wordpress. It is bound to be subject of exploits and attacks simply due to its popularity.

Comment: On the other hand, due to its popularity, it also gets security fixes out quite quickly and has a dead-simple update mechanism…

Comment: @ghoppe true. Still, the possibility of attack before a patch is released is greater, and targets easy to identify (Every WP installation < version x.y.z)

Comment: So you are suggesting for me to make a client-side (literally on my client's computer) CMS? I think I might try that! Thanks. Also, what if I were to write a bare-bones CMS with PHP? I doubt it's hard, and if the code is tiny, I can try and harden it (I would throw MySQL out of the window, so I might try writing to files instead of a database)...

Comment: @Blender there are various client-side apps, I think Macromedia/Adobe had a DW spin-off specialized on page editing for computer illiterate users. Or alternatively, yes, a CMS that runs on client side. But a custom PHP bare-bones CMS on the server would work as well, and can be built safely if essential security basics are followed. Hide the admin section behind a `.htaccess` password dialog, and if possible make it available to only the client's IP on Apache level. Maybe install the Suhosin PHP patch.

Comment: I was thinking, as the client *loves* email, to actually make a Python or PHP CMS that *just* serves content from a hidden email account's inbox. As for PHP, would I still need the patch (I use Lighttpd, so no Apache for me) if PHP was just serving? I'll whip up a quick email CMS later...

Thanks for inspiring me. I never even thought of a completely interaction-free CMS setup. Thanks!

Comment: @Blender If I were to build a solution for a paranoid customer, I would use PHP only to write out static resources - maybe even from a second server that is completely closed to the outside world (no open ports), and actively connects to - say - a IMAP mailbox to fetch new contents. Just to add another possibility. As for using PHP to serve data, I think Suhosin also protects against things like  huge request bodies that might cause a stack overflow and whatnot, so it might be a good idea nevertheless. Still, it is probably safe to stay with standard PHP if no interaction is possible

Comment: @Pekka I'll try to explain that to them ;), so PHP it is. I'm almost done with the rough version of whole thing, and now all I have to do is parse Gmail's insane message encoding schemes. If only my temporary free web host has `imap_open` as an allowed function... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the site is pure HTML, then the insecurity is in the server, or the connection made between the server and the client.

I'd look into how to make the server more secure before making changes to the site, although doing both is a good idea. CMS's like WordPress use MySQL databases to store posts, etc, so that means client -> server connections. A way to make transfers of data more secure is to use `https://` instead of vanilla `http://`. You can redirect using a `.htaccess` file if need be.

To summarise, I'd look at the server side of things for any vulnerabilities.

James

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has become a pretty wonderful CMS. If the site is high-risk, you might want to shy away from it, but I haven't had a site that I thought was too high-risk for WP myself. The site should keep up with regular updates and regular backups and there are some security tips that you can follow to help keep it more secure and less of a target.

**First. Hide WP on the front end**

Add this to your functions.php:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
remove_action('wp_head', 'rsd_link');
remove_action('wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link');
```

That will remove default header info that can be searched for by scripts.

Install wp in a directory that will help obscure its location and obscure the admin URL.

Change the name of wp-contents folder to something else and move it outside of the main wp directory. For instance, you could name it "includes" and put it into the root folder. and then links to template files will not have wp-contents in them.

On top of that, use a secure host, lock down your files (especially on shared hosting), and you can look at something like vaultpress, but it seems like if you use a solid backup plugin and a good host, that is unnecessary. You can also look at some of the security audit plugins, but don't keep them running after you get feedback.

This code in your wp-config.php file will help to install in a directory and move wp-contents outside of it into an "includes" folder:

```
define('WP_HOME',        'http://domain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL',     WP_HOME .'/admin');
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', WP_HOME .'/includes');
```

Comment: Of course, a dynamic site with server script and database will be more open, so if everyone is afraid of this, I would stick to regular HTML. I would not use security as an excuse to use a different CMS, or to build your own. If you build your own, you really have to pay attention to security, and I bet you won't be as good at it as a whole community of people. And you will give up all of the options and functionality you could of had with Wordpress.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already got my blind CMS system almost running. It uses emails as posts from a hidden address, but I'll tweak with WP when that fails...

Comment: That. system could be interesting, is a lot easier, and won't have as many security concerns, so I take back what I said in that case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Wordpress is good for blogs
2. Typo3 is a good cms but hard to learn at start
3. Joomla and Drupal can be used as cms

Comment: Commas and periods make anything look more readable ;) Thanks, I'll take a look at these.

Comment: Use vim? Did you read the question? "The site owners are completely technologically impaired..."